# I'm having requirement as explained below and i'm planning to use FAB. Is this the right approach?

Tags: android, tableview, floating-action-button

I need to create the button as shown in below image in the table view on each row.

[image: ScreenShot - 1]
Since this resembles the FAM/FAB, i thought of using the FAB/FAM.

On click of the button, it should expand as shown in the Screenshot - 2.

[image: Screenshot - 2]

Please let me know this is the right approach or is there any other alternative. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would start by comparing the different approaches, this question is too broad about how it can be achieved. Please simplify your question. Stackoverflow is not a research assistant. Also isn't it illegal to be posting your UX documents here? If your document says "confidential' you're in big trouble.

Comment: @JoxTraex I know it's not the research assistant, i'm asking the geeks opinion on approach that i'm going to follow. Without posting the required UX, how can one understand. Even after posting you are not able to understand.